# Producer-Consumer in Java - 1 item

Tags: java, producer-consumer

Could anyone kindly share the code snippet of java producer consumer program. The objective of the program is that at a given point of time there should be only 1 item. I know I should be using wait and notify but not able to get the complete snippet. Can this be done without using any kind of data structure?

Thanks in advance.

```
class Consumer extends Thread {
    private Good gObj;  
    Consumer(Good g) {
        gObj = g; 
    }
    public void run() {
        synchronized(gObj) {
            wait(); 
        } 
    } 
}

class Good { } 

public class Producer implements Runnable { 
    private Good gObj; 
    Producer(Good g) { 
        gObj = g; 
    }
    public void run() { 
        synchronized(gObj) { 
            notify(); 
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Good g = new Good();
        Producer p = new Producer(g);
        Thread producerThread = new Thread(p);
        producerThread.start();
        Consumer c = new Consumer(g);
        c.start();
   }
}
```

Comment: If you expect people to share code snippets, surely you should atleast make an effort to try sharing yours first. Also, could you maybe give us some context for this question? Like what you are trying to achieve, your intent, etc.

Comment: Are you trying to teach me manners or something that sort over here??:P And coming to the context that I have already mentioned in the question..

Comment: good i hav taken as item.. but am not sure what to do with it.. This is the code snippet I started with..

Comment: Not so much manners, but the only way to truly learn and grow is to try it out yourself and if you need help later on (after thoroughly thinking it through and trying alternate ways), then you may ask for assistance for any error(s) you might get.

Comment: @JoshM - ok cool... yeah I know the drill.. I have shared the code snippet,ppl might feel it was pretty straight forward thats y did not share earlier... Btwn if we use while (true), the program will never exit right, so I don't know how to carry forward the program from here...

Comment: @kushi: Show us your code, describe the problem you're having, what you're expecting to see and what you actually see, and what your attempts to solve the problem so far have been. http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: @kushi: Pasting an entire program with no indentation or line breaks into your question is also not a great way to get help. Anyways, your code has a lot of issues, but the nature of the issues suggests that you are not yet ready to take on this problem (not a bad thing, you just have some learning to do). Check out the wiki article on the topic as a good starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

Comment: @JasonC yeah sorry 4 dat.. nd thanks 4 ur help.. am back to this forum after a long tym.. By the tym I realized my mistake and tried 2 rectify it.. U already edited the code.. Thanks again...

Comment: @kushi No worries :) BTW, in addition to the wiki, the official Java tutorials have a basic producer/consumer example as one of the tutorials; should be a good read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: I think i have attached the code which I had tried along with the ques.. Then y its on hold??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Producer {   String producer = "once";

    /// returns the string and sets it to null
    // 
    String get() {
      String get = producer;
      producer = null;
      return get;
    }
}

class Consumer { Producer p = new Producer();
  Consumer() {
    out.println( "The value of producer is: " + p.get();
    out.println( "The value of producer is: " + p.get();
  }
}
```

> Can this be done without using any kind of data structure?

sure!

Comment: @kushi  You could look into using the jms that is included...